# Add custom prerequisites to ClickOnce in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have an application (C#, .Net4) which I'm publishing with ClickOnce. I need to verify that the machines installing it have 2 prerequisites, one is an `msi` file and the other is `exe`. I've tried the following solutions:

- Use the prerequisites option in the project's properties (under Publish) while putting the msi and the exe in the installation directory - no good.
- Install `Bootstrapper Manifest Generator` and following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15863/Add-your-own-custom-prerequisite-to-quot-ClickOnce), where I have a problem - the build succeeds but with `Attempted to access a path that is not on the disk.` warnings. It does generate the `package.xml` and `product.xml files, but the installation size didn't change and it does not install the prerequisites (I've also removed the app and tried to install rather than update).

I'm using VS2010, I'm not sure i this is the reason that BMG does not work.

I'd appreciate your help in solving this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no Bootstrapper Manifest Generator for vs 2010 but,
you can use Bootstrapper Manifest Generator for vs 2008 follow this link

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=bmg&ReleaseId=1567
after Boot strapper Generate your installation Package you need to copy Package
from   Document(your Package)
manual to this location "Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper"
for more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=vs.80%29.aspx